# What is the significance of Kundali in Hindu Family

Tags: astrology, horoscopes

When a baby is born in Hindu family the very first thing they do is prepare a *Kundali* of that child.

In that Kundali they draw a chart like

[image: Kundali]

From this Kundali the future of that guy is predicted. It is also used
to match with the Kundali of the other person before a couple decides to marry.

So what is the main significance of this Kundali in our life? and in what ways does it affects us?

Comment: The EditedToAdd question is off-topic. Please remove it. You should realize, we don't entertain questions asking for scientific logic...

Comment: @AwalGarg thank you for your suggestions but the i wanted to know about houses and planets and their placings. As i am not aware about that

Comment: you can ask this question on the Jyotisha SE proposal to get a more detailed answer: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101512/jyotisha?referrer=WNGAY2D0NY672-MEPBo36A2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kundali is the Hindi for what we call 'Horoscope' in English. It is a pretty widely used thing in astrology. It is based on the fact that heavenly bodies and their positions at the time of an event effects how the event goes on.

So in the case of the birth of a child, we record when he/she is born, at what place and other details. Astrologers, then on the basis of position of prominent stars, 7 planets, Sun and the Moon about that time create a chart, similar to the pic you posted (number of charts is not limited to 1).

The numbers in the various sections indicate the position of different heavenly bodies. By position, I don't mean position in space, but position corresponding to a specific house in the Kundali (which ultimately depends on some calculations based on the time and spatial position)...

Not only on the birth of someone, but astrologers also use the Horoscope calculation in numerous other events. When sacred rituals take place, we try to do them in specific time spans called *Shubh Mahurats* which are considered good. These time spans are predicted the same way Horoscopes are calculated, but in some different context.

*Shubh Mahuratas* are calculated/predicted for most things like marriages, ring-ceremony, baby-showers etc.

Nowadays, you can encounter that people first concern Astrologers for these time spans and request doctors to have their babies delivered near that *Shubh Mahurat* so that life of the baby be good. (*I know this is a bit weird, but it does happen, somewhat rarely though!*)

---

There are total 12 houses<sup>1</sup> in all. Each house can accommodate a heavenly body.

Each house also corresponds to specific areas of life. The first house, for example signifies life, longevity, self, health, nature and appearance of native; Complexion, vitality, sorrows, gains and profits to younger brothers and his friends. It governs head and face.

The heavenly body present in the house signifies how the person's life will go on in that area. These heavenly bodies keep changing their positions with time; thus, your daily horoscope changes. The change depends on which *graha* comes in.

Further detailed horoscope information for a particular person can be calculated for specific transits by astrologers, when given birth details.
This is done by seeing the most initial *graha* which was present in the house. Then, we calculate which *graha* will be more *strong*. If a strong (and good) *graha* comes in, life in that area will be good and vice versa.

<sub>1. [Reference - Astrology Basics](http://www.kpjyotish.com/Astrology_basics.htm) See this link for more details on houses.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Though, Kundali/Janampatri (or 'Horoscope' in English) may be prepared anytime by providing - date, month and year of birth along with time and place (longitude and latitude) Kundli is divided on 12 houses of 30 degrees each (total 360 degrees complete circle) and further divided into 27 Nakshtras. Each Nakshtras are further divided into four *charans or padas*. Planets according to their physical alignment at the time of birth as seen from place of birth are recorded in the kundli. There are nine planets : Sun, Moon, Mars, Mercury, Venus, Jupiter, Saturn , Rahu and Ketu. (Rahu and Ketu though nodes of earth but are treated as planets for all astrological purpose).

Kundli is the map of your journey of life. The position of the ascendant, signs, house(s) and planets in the Kundli determines the incidents of your life. **The incidents of your life are determined by the Kundli which can not be changed but their auspiciousness can be maintained if you perform good deeds and help others.**

Kundli is prepared at the time birth to ascertain the alphabet according to the charan of the nakshatra. That alphabet *maybe* used to keep the name of the child. Also, Kundli is seen for any immediate such as health (even death) of child. In case, of any negative planetary influence, appropriate remedies such as *pooja , havan , daan* etc are performed/done.

Through a Kundli, one can ascertain any details about the *jatak's* (the person whose chart is being checked) life. It is possible to check for health, work and what kind of work, general life, wealth, friends, enemies, spouse(s), legal matters and many more things. Matchmaking is also done through this, the usual matching practice is matching of Gunas and checking for Manglik Dosha which are both incomplete as they check primarily 1 planet out of 9. A good astrologer will check the Kundli for all 9 planets.

The happiness and sorrowfulness in your life comes according to the work you performed in previous birth. Therefore if you perform good deeds, spiritual and charitable activities then you will face minor problems or obstacles in your life. The Kundli and Muhurta are interrelated because if you perform auspicious tasks and events in an auspicious Muhurta according to your birth-chart, you will be happy and your problems may also get reduced. Therefore, the need of the hour is to give primacy to Muhurta for performing any auspicious event.

Comment: Though I believe in astrology, I have a doubt since long. Even if we name a baby according its horoscope, even if we do all the poojas to nullify the negative aspects, though we check the horoscopes of the couple before marriage, not all persons are successful in life, they do meet with failures; not all marriages continue happily, some do get divorced. What could possibly be the reason for these kind of failures even after doing everything in accordance with the astrology? I didn't know such a question would be on-topic or not. That's why I posted it as a comment here. :)

Comment: I highlighted in the answer above. In simplest terms, Karma bound your action and thoughts binds you to karma. So by knowing your horoscope details you can see results of your past karma, now which you have to bear but by performing remedies you can reduce it and in some cases very significantly. Eg. if you are about to incur a loss , then by performing remedy your loss will be reduced but loss surely take place because you are bound by karma.

Answer (score 1):

First we have to know one thing that , whole universe is one organic unity so whatever happening in universe indirectly or directly effect us and other things in a way. It could be good or bad , But it can be changed through the channeling of energy by different ways.Its a science which assist to be in harmony with universe.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

Horoscope/Kundali is the encoded form of a person's past Karmas, intrinsic nature and Agami Karmas based on planetary and constellation positions at the time of birth of a person.

[Outwitting the Stars - Chapter 16 of Autobiography of a Yogi by Paramhansa Yogananda](https://www.crystalclarity.com/yogananda/chapter-16/)

> “Mukunda, why don’t you get an astrological armlet?”
>
> “Should I, Master? I don’t believe in astrology.”
>
> “It is never a question of belief; the only scientific attitude one
>   can take on any subject is whether it is true. The law of gravitation
>   worked as efficiently before Newton as after him. The cosmos would be
>   fairly chaotic if its laws could not operate without the sanction of
>   human belief.
>
> **“Charlatans have brought the stellar science to its present state of
>   disrepute. Astrology is too vast, both mathematically and
>   philosophically, to be rightly grasped except by men of profound
>   understanding.** If ignoramuses misread the heavens, and see there a
>   scrawl instead of a script, that is to be expected in this imperfect
>   world. One should not dismiss the wisdom with the ‘wise.’
>
> “All parts of creation are linked together and interchange their
>   influences. The balanced rhythm of the universe is rooted in
>   reciprocity,” my guru continued. “Man, in his human aspect, has to
>   combat two sets of forces—first, the tumults within his being, caused
>   by the admixture of earth, water, fire, air, and ethereal elements;
>   second, the outer disintegrating powers of nature. So long as man
>   struggles with his mortality, he is affected by the myriad mutations
>   of heaven and earth.
>
> **“Astrology is the study of man’s response to planetary stimuli. The
>   stars have no conscious benevolence or animosity; they merely send
>   forth positive and negative radiations.** Of themselves, these do not
>   help or harm humanity, but offer a lawful channel for the outward
>   operation of cause-effect equilibriums which each man has set into
>   motion in the past.
>
> **“A child is born on that day and at that hour when the celestial rays
>   are in mathematical harmony with his individual karma. His horoscope
>   is a challenging portrait, revealing his unalterable past and its
>   probable future results. But the natal chart can be rightly
>   interpreted only by men of intuitive wisdom: these are few.**
>
> “The message boldly blazoned across the heavens at the moment of birth
>   is not meant to emphasize fate the result of past good and evil but to
>   arouse man’s will to escape from his universal thralldom. What he has
>   done, he can undo. None other than himself was the instigator of the
>   causes of whatever effects are now prevalent in his life. He can
>   overcome any limitation, because he created it by his own actions in
>   the first place, and because he has spiritual resources which are not
>   subject to planetary pressure.
>
> “Superstitious awe of astrology makes one an automaton, slavishly
>   dependent on mechanical guidance. The wise man defeats his planets
>   which is to say, his pastby transferring his allegiance from the
>   creation to the Creator. The more he realizes his unity with Spirit,
>   the less he can be dominated by matter. The soul is ever-free; it is
>   deathless because birthless. It cannot be regimented by stars.
>
> “Man is a soul, and has a body. When he properly places his sense of
>   identity, he leaves behind all compulsive patterns. So long as he
>   remains confused in his ordinary state of spiritual amnesia, he will
>   know the subtle fetters of environmental law.
>
> “God is harmony; the devotee who attunes himself will never perform
>   any action amiss. His activities will be correctly and naturally timed
>   to accord with astrological law. After deep prayer and meditation he
>   is in touch with his divine consciousness; there is no greater power
>   than that inward protection.”
>
> “Then, dear Master, why do you want me to wear an astrological
>   bangle?” I ventured this question after a long silence, during which I
>   had tried to assimilate Sri Yukteswar’s noble exposition.
>
> “It is only when a traveler has reached his goal that he is justified
>   in discarding his maps. During the journey, he takes advantage of any
>   convenient short cut. The ancient rishis discovered many ways to
>   curtail the period of man’s exile in delusion. There are certain
>   mechanical features in the law of karma which can be skillfully
>   adjusted by the fingers of wisdom.
>
> “All human ills arise from some transgression of universal law. The
>   scriptures point out that man must satisfy the laws of nature, while
>   not discrediting the divine omnipotence. He should say: ‘Lord, I trust
>   in Thee, and know Thou canst help me, but I too will do my best to
>   undo any wrong I have done.’ By a number of means by prayer, by will
>   power, by yoga meditation, by consultation with saints, by use of
>   astrological bangles the adverse effects of past wrongs can be
>   minimized or nullified.
>
> “Just as a house can be fitted with a copper rod to absorb the shock
>   of lightning, so the bodily temple can be benefited by various
>   protective measures. Ages ago our yogis discovered that pure metals
>   emit an astral light which is powerfully counteractive to negative
>   pulls of the planets. Subtle electrical and magnetic radiations are
>   constantly circulating in the universe; when a man’s body is being
>   aided, he does not know it; when it is being disintegrated, he is
>   still in ignorance. Can he do anything about it?
>
> “This problem received attention from our rishis; they found helpful
>   not only a combination of metals, but also of plants and most
>   effective of all faultless jewels of not less than two carats. The
>   preventive uses of astrology have seldom been seriously studied
>   outside of India. One little-known fact is that the proper jewels,
>   metals, or plant preparations are valueless unless the required weight
>   is secured, and unless these remedial agents are worn next to the
>   skin.”
>
> “Sir, of course I shall take your advice and get a bangle. I am
>   intrigued at the thought of outwitting a planet!”
>
> “For general purposes I counsel the use of an armlet made of gold,
>   silver, and copper. But for a specific purpose I want you to get one
>   of silver and lead.” Sri Yukteswar added careful directions.
>
> “Guruji, what ‘specific purpose’ do you mean?”
>
> “The stars are about to take an unfriendly interest in you, Mukunda.
>   Fear not; you shall be protected. In about a month your liver will
>   cause you much trouble. The illness is scheduled to last for six
>   months, but your use of an astrological armlet will shorten the period
>   to twenty-four days.”
>
> I sought out a jeweler the next day, and was soon wearing the bangle.
>   My health was excellent; Master’s prediction slipped from my mind. He
>   left Serampore to visit Benares. Thirty days after our conversation, I
>   felt a sudden pain in the region of my liver. The following weeks were
>   a nightmare of excruciating pain. Reluctant to disturb my guru, I
>   thought I would bravely endure my trial alone.
>
> But twenty-three days of torture weakened my resolution; I entrained
>   for Benares. There Sri Yukteswar greeted me with unusual warmth, but
>   gave me no opportunity to tell him my woes in private. Many devotees
>   visited Master that day, just for a darshan.Ill and neglected, I sat
>   in a corner. It was not until after the evening meal that all guests
>   had departed. My guru summoned me to the octagonal balcony of the
>   house.
>
> “You must have come about your liver disorder.” Sri Yukteswar’s gaze
>   was averted; he walked to and fro, occasionally intercepting the
>   moonlight. “Let me see; you have been ailing for twenty-four days,
>   haven’t you?”
>
> “Yes, sir.”
>
> “Please do the stomach exercise I have taught you.”
>
> “If you knew the extent of my suffering, Master, you would not ask me
>   to exercise.” Nevertheless I made a feeble attempt to obey him.
>
> “You say you have pain; I say you have none. How can such
>   contradictions exist?” My guru looked at me inquiringly.
>
> I was dazed and then overcome with joyful relief. No longer could I
>   feel the continuous torment that had kept me nearly sleepless for
>   weeks; at Sri Yukteswar’s words the agony vanished as though it had
>   never been.
>
> I started to kneel at his feet in gratitude, but he quickly prevented
>   me.
>
> “Don’t be childish. Get up and enjoy the beauty of the moon over the
>   Ganges.” But Master’s eyes were twinkling happily as I stood in
>   silence beside him. I understood by his attitude that he wanted me to
>   feel that not he, but God, had been the Healer.
>
> I wear even now the heavy silver and lead bangle, a memento of that
>   daylong-past, ever-cherished when I found anew that I was living with
>   a personage indeed superhuman. On later occasions, when I brought my
>   friends to Sri Yukteswar for healing, he invariably recommended jewels
>   or the bangle, extolling their use as an act of astrological wisdom.
>
> I had been prejudiced against astrology from my childhood, partly
>   because I observed that many people are sequaciously attached to it,
>   and partly because of a prediction made by our family astrologer: “You
>   will marry three times, being twice a widower.” I brooded over the
>   matter, feeling like a goat awaiting sacrifice before the temple of
>   triple matrimony.
>
> **“The deeper the self-realization of a man, the more he influences the
>   whole universe by his subtle spiritual vibrations, and the less he
>   himself is affected by the phenomenal flux.”** These words of Master’s
>   often returned inspiringly to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the importance of Kundli, we need to understand the importance of Astrology. Although the question ask here is different, the answer is quite relevant:

> Q. Dear Gurudev, astrologically I am under the influence of Rahu-Shani
> planetary combination. This has made me frustrated, angry, and
> irritable most of the time. I am going away from the spiritual path
> and creating trouble for others around me. Please help.
>
> A:  At least you have this knowledge. If you have understood
> this much, then you know that all these negative emotions are just a
> passing phase. You know this is because of some planetary combination.
> This is where astrology comes to your help in a big way. Suppose you
> didn’t know that it is because of these planetary combinations, what
> would happen to you? You would brand the whole world as negative. You
> will think you are negative and you will feel dejected forever, isn’t
> it so?
>
> That is why *Jyotish* (astrology) is called the Eye of Wisdom. It makes
> you see beyond your immediate situation, and know that it is only for
> a short time, and it is going to change. You gain some unknown inner
> strength from this. And you will not start blaming yourself or people
> around you.
>
> It is always better to blame the planets because they are so far away.
> You can’t do anything about them. They move at their own pace, you
> can’t hasten their movement.
>
> Whenever things go wrong, the natural tendency is to blame yourself or
> blame others. In either case you are at a loss. But when you put the
> blame on the planets you are free from blaming others and blaming
> yourself. So a certain degree of sanity comes into your life. This is
> one advantage of it.
>
> You should know there is always a remedy for this. What is it? Adoring
> the Divine. On top of all the planets is Lord Shiva or the Shiva
> Tattva. So by chanting Om Namah Shivaya, you will sail through all
> this.
>
> I tell you, in any of these unfavourable situations there is always an
> advantage, i.e., turning more inward and becoming more spiritual. In
> favourable situations your mind is outward, so at least in
> unfavourable situations you can turn your mind inward and utilize this
> time for prayer and meditation.
>
> All of these, Rahu Bhukti, Shani Bhukti, Ketu Bhukti, etc., are all
> very good for spiritual growth. The main purpose of Shani (one of the
> nine cosmic influencers in Hindu astrology) is to make you more
> spiritual. And how does he do it? When you are clinging on to the
> outer, he brings problem there to bring you inward.
>
> If you are already inward, he does not have anything much to do. His
> job is done so there will not be any problem also. Even if problems
> are there they would be minimum, they will just come and go. So every
> situation can be used for one’s benefit.

From an article by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar:

http://www.artofliving.org/astrology---eye-wisdom