# Is the practice of kundalis matching part of the core Hindu doctrine?

Tags: rig-veda, astrology, kundali

The answer to this question: [What is the significance of Kundali in Hindu Family](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/642/2349)  seems to indicate that Hindu astrology is a core component of the Hindu doctrine.

My understanding is that the core texts of the Hindu doctrine are the Rigveda and according to this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_astrology

> ... historical documentation shows that horoscopic astrology in the Indian subcontinent came from Hellenistic influences, post-dating the Vedic period.[4]

Which seems to suggest that Hindu astrology may have been assimilated later on into the Hindu doctrine.

It seems that kundalis is something practiced by families that believe in Hindu astrology but since that was a later addition to the Hindu doctrine it is not a core component but rather a historical accident.

I know that in this SE site, western sources are frowned upon, so I would like to request more reliable sources to understand if indeed the idea of kundalis matching has any basis in the Hindu doctrine.

Comment: The Rig Veda is the oldest veda, but it should not be considered "the" core text. If you want to read a good scholarly work on how western scholars distort Hinduism, Read "Invading The Sacred". Available as a free download here - http://rajivmalhotra.com/books/invading-sacred/  Hindu astrology is one of the sciences mentioned as such in the vedas. It is not a religious doctrine. Hindu astrology does not resemble Western astrology at all. It's an old story from the 19th century Orientalists that many Eastern things came from "Hellenistic influences".

Comment: None of the canonical scriptures of vedic literature mention "horoscope matching"  as a criteria for marriage although stars, planets, horoscopes, etc. are part of vedic literature. Horoscope matching started only around 17th/18th century due to a text called "kAlaprakaShika"

Answer (score 4):

Vedas are studied through Vedangas. Vedangas are limbs of Vedas. There are six vedangas. The six Vedangas are Siksha, Chhanda, Vyakarana, Nirukta, **Jyotisha** and Kalpa.

Hence study of Vedas is incomplete without Jyotish (science of Astrology)..
**_____________________________________**
Here are some refrences from Vedas:

> RV3.54.19 May the Gods' envoy, sent to many a quarter, proclaim us sinless for our perfect safety. May Earth and Heaven, the Sun, the waters, **hear us,** and the wide firmament and constellations.

Here is the word 'hear us' which certainly represents a method of astrology.

> RV1.50.2 **The constellations pass away, like thieves**, together with their beams, Before the all-beholding Sun.

This verse is the core of vedic astrological doctrines where movement of constellations are calculated with respect to earth

> By Soma are the Adityas strong, by Soma mighty is the earth. **Thus Soma in the midst of all these constellations hath his place.** RV10.85.2

This verse is the core of vedic astrological doctrines which makes Moon lord of the constellation/ nakshtras.

**____________________________________**

> “Dawn is the head of the sacrificial horse. Heaven is his eye. The year is his soul. **His form are the nakshatras** and the stars are his bones”. Taittiriya Samhita of Yajur Veda VII 5.25

Atharva Veda in 19.7 mentions the name of 28 constellation/ nakshtras.

Atharva Veda 19.7

> **A Prayer to the Lunar Mansions and other Powers for protection and prosperity**
>
> 1The brilliant lights shining in heaven together, which through the world glide on with rapid motion. And Days, and Firmament with songs I worship, **seeking the Twenty-eight-fold for its favour.**
>
> 2**Krittikās, Rohinī** be swift to hear me! Let **Mrigasiras** bless me, help me **Ārdrā!**
>   **Punarvasu and Sūnritā, fair Pushya, the Sun, Asleshās, Maghā** lead me onward!
>
> 3My bliss be **Svāti and benignant Chitrā**, my right First **Phalgunis and present Hasta. Rādhas, Visākhas, gracious Anurādhā, Jyeshthā and happy starred uninjured Mūla.**
>
> 4Food shall be earlier **Ashādhas** grant me; let those that follow bring me strength and vigour; With virtuous merit **Abhijit endow me! Sravana and Sravishthās** make me prosper.
>
> 5**Satabhishak** afford me ample freedom, and **both the Proshtha-padas** guard me safely. **Revati and the Asvayujas bring me luck, and the Bharanis** abundant riches!
>
> 1Benign to me be all those Lunar Mansions to which the Moon as he moves on doth honour.
>   **_______________________________________**

Similarly Brihad Aranyaka Upanishad of Yajurveda in VI-iii-1:

> He who wishes to attain greatness (should perform) on an auspicious day in a fortnight in which the moon waxes, and **under a male constellation, during the northward march of the sun,**

Benefitting something using position of planets and star is a part of horoscopic astrology.
**____________________________________**
Valmiki Ramayan is considered Adi-Kavya, the first written book in Sanskrit. Vedas aren't considered written they are considered revealed. See how sage Valmiki describes birth of Lord Rama in Ramayana.

> ततो यज्ञे समाप्ते तु ऋतूनाम् षट् समत्ययुः |
>   ततः च द्वादशे मासे चैत्रे नावमिके तिथौ || १८-८
>   नक्क्षत्रे अदिति दैवत्ये स्व उच्छ संस्थेषु पंचसु |
>   ग्रहेषु कर्कटे लग्ने वाक्पता इंदुना सह || १८-९
>   प्रोद्यमाने जगन्नाथम् सर्व लोक नमस्कृतम् |
>   कौसल्या अजनयत् रामम् सर्व लक्षण संयुतम् || १८-१०
>   विष्णोः अर्धम् महाभागम् पुत्रम् ऐक्ष्वाकु नंदनम् |
>   लोहिताक्षम् महाबाहुम् रक्त ओष्टम् दुंदुभि स्वनम् ||१८-११
>
> **Twice six months had rolled a way since the great sacrifice was over and, in the first month of the New Year, on the ninth day of the bright fortnight,** the Lord of the worlds chose to take human form and sent down half of His essence as the son of Kausalya (thenceforth to be known as Rama), the world-honored One, the crowning glory ot the grand line of Ikshwku, and the sum of all perfections. The constellation Punarvasu, of which Aditi was the regent, was chosen to preside at his birth. **The Sun, Mars, Jupiter, Venus, and Saturn were in ascension in their respective houses. Aries, Capricornus, Cancer, Pisces and the Libra, Jupiter and the Moon were in conjunction ; the rising sign was Cancer.** And KausalyA, shone with unparalleled effulgence, even as Aditi when she gave birth to Indra, the lord of the Shining Ones, the Vajra-wielder.

From above verse to verse translation of Valmiki Ramayana you can see that astronomy is described in horoscopic/astrological way.
**________________________________________**
Simiarly see Udyoga Parva CXLIII of Mahabharata where Karna describes omen to Lord Krishna:

Mahabharat Udyoga Parva CXLIII

> All these omens, making the hairs (of the spectators) stand on their ends, indicate, O
>   thou of Vrishni's race, the defeat of Dhritarashtra's son and the victory of Yudhishthira. **That fierce planet of great effulgence, Sanaischara (Saturn), is afflicting the constellation called Rohini, in order to afflict greatly the creatures of the earth. The planet Angaraka (Mars), wheeling, O slayer of Madhu, towards the constellation Jeshthya, approacheth towards Anuradhas, indicating a great slaughter of friends. Without doubt, O Krishna, a terrible calamity approacheth the Kurus when specially, O thou of Vrishni's race, the planet Mahapat afflicteth the constellation Chitra. The spot on the lunar disc hath changed its position; and Rahu also approacheth towards the sun.** Meteors are falling from the sky with loud noise and trembling motion.

**______________________________________**

It clearly mentions position of planets with respect to constellation which is horoscopic astrology. Hence Horoscopic astrology is also a core of vedic doctrines. If character of person can be defined by planetary position, then matching two kundalis is just it's another aspect.

Comment: None of the canonical scriptures of vedic literature (incl above references) mention "horoscope matching"  as a criteria for marriage although stars, planets, horoscopes, etc. are part of vedic literature. Horoscope matching started only around 17th/18th century due to a text called "kAlaprakaShika"

Answer (score 2):

Does practice of Kundalis or *Jyotisha* core of the Hindu doctrine? No
There is an abundance of [Hindu texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_texts) and each one is important like *Jyotisha* is and nothing forms a core.

Also, there might have been Hellenestic influences as you mention. These influences are common when information exchange happens. Similarly, Jyotisha has influenced Hellenistic and Islamic astrology. *Shri K.N.Rao*, one of the most eminent Indian *Jyotish* talks about such influence in this [video](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi194LKibDMAhVKBI4KHZahDhoQtwIIOjAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D0GpMqLO4A_U&usg=AFQjCNFTIz1I2WCkFnHY7rQpJo123SrCVA&sig2=rb1n_3lJFaVgy1KT9TGAQw).

> Also, I would like to refute your claim that Jyotisha was a
>   'historical accident'.  [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brihat_Parashara_Hora_Shastra) was created
>   by *Sage Parashara*, father of *Vedavyasa* who was the compiler of the
>   epic *Mahabharata*. The [*Bhrigu Saṃhitā*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhrigu_Samhita) is an *Jyotish* classic
>   attributed to *Maharishi Bhrigu* during the Vedic period, *Treta
>   yuga.* Also, there were exemplary *Jyotish* texts written later on.
>   You can look for *Phaladeepika* by *Mantreswara*, *Brihat Jataka* by
>   *Varahamira* and *Jataka Parijata* by *Vaidyanatha*.

It would suffice to say that Jyotisha forms an essential, if not core, part of the Vedic culture.

Answer (score 1):

The Nakshatras are in the vedas. There is something called the Nakshtra suktam that lists them. This is one aspect of Vedic astrology. As for the rest of it, this is considered more mundane knowledge and perhaps is not so deeply touched by the Vedas, but I would not be surprised at all if some elements were there. Jyotish (astrology) is like Ayurveda, in the sense that it is Vedanga, limbs of the Vedas meaning knowledge that is extrapolated from Vedic wisdom. If you were a great Brahmana Rishi of ancient lore, knowing astrology was considered sacred knowledge. Parashara and Jaimini are two Vedic sages who certainly possessed this knowledge. Indeed, many of the great saints were predicted from astrology, Krishna had his Kundali done, as did Lord Buddha, and even Jesus. This knowledge is very ancient, but it is quite possible that it has also been misunderstood over the ages. For example, in Srimad Bhagavatam (a Purana) it is stated that Aries and Libra are defined by the Spring and Fall equinoxes. But this is not the way Kundali's are drawn by most astrologers in India, they use a different definition. And it is Veda Vyasa who is said to wrote down Bhagavata Purana, the same who wrote down the Vedas for the Kali Yuga. Certainly true Jyotish is sacred Vedic knowledge, but the question is are we practicing it correctly? I think there are very few astrologers who know it well these days. Beware of most of them, they are like the fake sadhus. People are easily cheated. We are coming into a new age now where astrology will be validated scientifically, once we can come to an understanding of what Vedic astrology actually is. This is like the caste system, Varnashrama is a Vedic institution, but the way it is practiced today is a perversion. One is a brahmin by his qualities and life potential, not by his birth. Great saints have been born from shudra type families have they not? But much of India acts as though one must be born to a brahmin family.

If you study Parashara and Jaimini, you will realize that these sort of techniques are so detailed and pregnant with wisdom that it is highly unlikely they came anywhere but from the mind of a Vedic sage.

Comment: When giving an answer, you need to cite sources. Saying "in the Gita" or "in the vedas" is not citing a source. You need to be specific.