# What are the name of Hindu months based on Sun-god?

Tags: scripture, bhagavata-purana, surya

This question [The story behind Names of Hindu calender Months?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13900/the-story-behind-names-of-hindu-calender-months) describes the popular name of Hindu months. These are as [follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_calendar#Month_names):

> Chaitra, Vaiśākha, Jyeṣṭha, Āṣāḍha, Śrāvaṇa, Bhādrapada, Ashvin, Kārtika, Agrahāyaṇa (Mārgaśīrṣa), Pauṣa, Māgha, Phālguna

These months are related to Moon-god and may be called as Lunar Months. Now I am looking for the name of Hindu Solar Months.

So my question is, does Hindu Solar Months exist? If yes, which scripture describe of the name of months related to Sun-god? And are those name of months related to twelve Adityas?

Comment: http://harekrsna.de/surya/12adityas.htm

Comment: @Pandya Interesting!... oh so .. then there are solar months name too... I didn't knew...

Comment: Also note that Sun rules one moth on each Rashi (Mesh, Vrishabh,...,Meen etc. 12) and sometimes also refereed as solar month.

Comment: @Tezz I have found the answer in Bhagvatam.

Comment: @Triyugi Narayan Mani Oh!... it's interesting...!! Thanks for that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The months related to Sun-god are described in [Srimad Bhagvatam, Twelfth canto, chapter 11](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/11).

All twelve months are related to twelve Adityas as described in Bhagvatam by Sri Sūta Gosvāmī to Śrī Śaunaka.

> SB 12.11.33 — My dear sage, Dhātā as the sun-god, Kṛtasthalī as the Apsarā, Heti as the Rākṣasa, Vāsuki as the Nāga, Rathakṛt as the Yakṣa, Pulastya as the sage and Tumburu as the Gandharva rule the **month of Madhu**.
>
> SB 12.11.34 — Aryamā as the sun-god, Pulaha as the sage, Athaujā as the Yakṣa, Praheti as the Rākṣasa, Puñjikasthalī as the Apsarā, Nārada as the Gandharva and Kacchanīra as the Nāga rule the **month of Mādhava**.
>
> SB 12.11.35 — Mitra as the sun-god, Atri as the sage, Pauruṣeya as the Rākṣasa, Takṣaka as the Nāga, Menakā as the Apsarā, Hāhā as the Gandharva and Rathasvana as the Yakṣa rule the **month of Śukra**.
>
> SB 12.11.36 — Vasiṣṭha as the sage, Varuṇa as the sun-god, Rambhā as the Apsarā, Sahajanya as the Rākṣasa, Hūhū as the Gandharva, Śukra as the Nāga and Citrasvana as the Yakṣa rule the **month of Śuci**.
>
> SB 12.11.37 — Indra as the sun-god, Viśvāvasu as the Gandharva, Śrotā as the Yakṣa, Elāpatra as the Nāga, Aṅgirā as the sage, Pramlocā as the Apsarā and Varya as the Rākṣasa rule the **month of Nabhas**.
>
> SB 12.11.38 — Vivasvān as the sun-god, Ugrasena as the Gandharva, Vyāghra as the Rākṣasa, Āsāraṇa as the Yakṣa, Bhṛgu as the sage, Anumlocā as the Apsarā and Śaṅkhapāla as the Nāga rule the **month of Nabhasya**.
>
> SB 12.11.39 — Pūṣā as the sun-god, Dhanañjaya as the Nāga, Vāta as the Rākṣasa, Suṣeṇa as the Gandharva, Suruci as the Yakṣa, Ghṛtācī as the Apsarā and Gautama as the sage rule the **month of Tapas**.
>
> SB 12.11.40 — Ṛtu as the Yakṣa, Varcā as the Rākṣasa, Bharadvāja as the sage, Parjanya as the sun-god, Senajit as the Apsarā, Viśva as the Gandharva and Airāvata as the Nāga rule the **month known as Tapasya**.
>
> SB 12.11.41 — Aṁśu as the sun-god, Kaśyapa as the sage, Tārkṣya as the Yakṣa, Ṛtasena as the Gandharva, Urvaśī as the Apsarā, Vidyucchatru as the Rākṣasa and Mahāśaṅkha as the Nāga rule the **month of Sahas**.
>
> SB 12.11.42 — Bhaga as the sun-god, Sphūrja as the Rākṣasa, Ariṣṭanemi as the Gandharva, Ūrṇa as the Yakṣa, Āyur as the sage, Karkoṭaka as the Nāga and Pūrvacitti as the Apsarā rule the **month of Puṣya**.
>
> SB 12.11.43 — Tvaṣṭā as the sun-god; Jamadagni, the son of Ṛcīka, as the sage; Kambalāśva as the Nāga; Tilottamā as the Apsarā; Brahmāpeta as the Rākṣasa; Śatajit as the Yakṣa; and Dhṛtarāṣṭra as the Gandharva maintain the **month of Iṣa**.
>
> SB 12.11.44 — Viṣṇu as the sun-god, Aśvatara as the Nāga, Rambhā as the Apsarā, Sūryavarcā as the Gandharva, Satyajit as the Yakṣa, Viśvāmitra as the sage and Makhāpeta as the Rākṣasa rule the **month of Ūrja**.