# Is the word Yahweh present in Rig Veda?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

[This post](https://swarajyamag.com/ideas/is-the-yahweh-of-abrahamism-originally-rig-vedic-if-it-is-many-long-held-assumptions-must-be-challenged) from Swarajya claims the word Yahweh appears in Rig Veda multiple times.

> The common thread is one word – Yahweh, which can be found in both the
> Rig Veda, and in the Old Testament – the oldest Abrahamic text.

Is the word Yahweh present in Rig Veda?
If yes then where exactly does the word Yahweh occurs in Rig Veda?

Comment: how is Yahweh written in Devanagari?.. is it like याह्वे ?

Comment: @Tezz even I'm not sure. But the author claims such.

Comment: @Optimus if some article claims "Yahweh" is present in Rigveda, shouldn't they provide verses too?

Comment: @TheDestroyer exactly my point. But articles simply says so. I couldn't find the verses.

Comment: Yahweh is ancient aramaic, not sanskrit. This question can only be answered by a scholar(s) versed in both ancient aramaic and sanskrit 1) This is not a question for this forum. 2) When posting a question links are not questions. You should write within the question what you want to ask about and provide the link as a source.

Comment: No it is not. Why bother asking such a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If by 'Yahweh' you mean the word `यह्वं` = *yahvaṃ*. Then yes, it does occur in the Rig-Veda.

Searching it on the [sa.wiki repository](https://sa.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search=%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%82%20&title=%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%83%3A%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D&go=%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D&ns0=1) yields multiple results of its occurrence (around more than 30)
 in the Rig-Veda itself, besides other Vedas.

Some instances are -

> [ṛgvedaḥ sūktaṃ 1.36](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%8B%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%83_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%82_%E0%A5%A7.%E0%A5%A9%E0%A5%AC)
>
> प्र वो **यह्वं** पुरूणां विशां देवयतीनाम् । अग्निं
> सूक्तेभिर्वचोभिरीमहे यं सीमिदन्य ईळते ॥१॥

> [ṛgvedaḥ sūktaṃ 5.16](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%8B%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%83_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%82_%E0%A5%AB.%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%AC)
>
> अधा ह्यग्न एषां सुवीर्यस्य मंहना । तमिद् **यह्वं** न रोदसी परि श्रवो
> बभूवतुः ॥४॥

> [ṛgvedaḥ sūktaṃ 8.13](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%8B%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%83_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%82_%E0%A5%AE.%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A9)
>
> तदिद्रुद्रस्य चेतति **यह्वं** प्रत्नेषु धामसु । मनो यत्रा वि
> तद्दधुर्विचेतसः ॥२०॥

> [ṛgvedaḥ sūktaṃ 10.92](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%8B%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%83_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%82_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A6.%E0%A5%AF%E0%A5%A8)
>
> इममञ्जस्पामुभये अकृण्वत धर्माणमग्निं विदथस्य साधनम् ।
>  अक्तुं न
> **यह्व**मुषसः पुरोहितं तनूनपातमरुषस्य निंसते ॥२॥

As regards the meaning of the word, a classical search in the [KST dictionary](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/yahva?q=%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%82) yields -

> **Monier Williams Cologne**
>  यह्व॑ mf(ई॑)n. restless, swift, active
> (**applied to Agni, Indra and Soma**), RV.
>
> continually moving or flowing (applied to the waters), ib. (= महत्,
> Sāy.)
>
> यह्व॑ m. = यजमान, a sacrificer, Uṇ. i, १३४ Sch.
>
> **Macdonell**
>
> यह्व
>
> yah-vá, RV. a. (ī) restless, active, swift;
>
> constant; ever-flowing.

And in [Nirukta 8.8](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83), it is thus defined as -

> यह्व इति महतो नामधेयम्
>
> > Yahweh, therefore means, the great name.

Comment: Isn't the Yaahweh or याह्वे, you have quoted Yahwa or  यह्व.  Can you once search for याह्वे?

Comment: Well, `याह्वे` would be yāhve in IAST. And, I don't think याह्वे is present in the Rig-Veda. It's यह्व only.  @Optimus

Comment: Why can't I give bounty to you? Is there some time limit?

Comment: Anyway great answer, thanks a lot, I request you to please try to answer my other questions

Comment: Can you please help me with this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/52042/27623

Comment: And this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13900/27623

Comment: @Optimus ok thanks, let me see and research a bit. I'll let you know by tomorrow if I can answer them. :)