# When does a Mahadasha start for an individual?

Tags: astrology, nakshatra

When does a Mahadasha start for an individual?

For eg, for a person born in Punarvasu nakshatra when does his Guru-Mahadasha start? Just at the time of his birth or any other particular time? How to find it?

Comment: Read here: http://www.hinduastrology.com/astrology/readarticle/Know%20your%20Dasha

Comment: @Tezz btw if astrology/jyotisha upaveda was established to predict muhurat for the Yagnakarma then why do we exploit it by using it for personal benifits?

Comment: @Yogi it's true that Jyotish was used in muhurta prediction for Yajna karma... however personal use is not it's exploitation... they are also recommend by Rishis... Read this chapter of ValmikiRamayana where Valmiki describes auspicious signs and planetary position of Ramas birth..http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga18/bala_18_frame.htm also see my answer here... http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7465/is-the-practice-of-kundalis-matching-part-of-the-core-hindu-doctrine however people nowadays are exploiting astrology by Over-Marketing it...

Comment: @Tezz so it means we can compare a child birth with yagnakarma?

Comment: @Yogi Vishnu Purana states "The entire world is Transmutation of Yajna".... Everything here taking place is actually Yajna....

Comment: @Viki exact calculation can only be done with birth time and birth place... however I just made approximate calculation... Guru Mahadasha already finished on 2000... Upto 2019 you are under Shani Mahadasha... after that Budha Mahadasha starts... However GuruDasha also starts around August 2017 under Shani Mahadasha... (only apprx. Calculation)

Answer (score 1):

MahA-dashA start from the birth and continue until death. They are based on the nakshatra in which moon is progressing. So the dasha during birth will be determined by nakshatra of the moon. The degrees already traveled by the moon in the specific star is already completed period and remaining period will be the balance of the dasha remaining.

After the first dasha, the commencing dashas will run in a specific sequence in a specific time frame.

**For punarvasu nakshatra the first dasha will be of Jupiter during the birth. The period of dasha will be calculated by degrees of the moon.**

> The divisional longitude of each of the 27 nakshatras beginning with
>   Ashwini and ending with Revati is 13 degrees and 20 minutes further
>   divided into four quarters or padas. Each of the nine planets presides
>   over a set of three nakshatras situated on the zodiac at a trine from
>   each other. The commencing dasha or mahadasha at the time of birth
>   will be that of the lord of the nakshatra in which the Moon is placed,
>   which particular nakshatra is known as the "Janma nakshatra". If the
>   Moon is in Taurus in Mrigsira the first dasha will be of Mars, the
>   second will be that of Rahu and so on. The distance already covered by
>   the Moon in Mrigsira will be the portion of the dasha of Mars that has
>   elapsed; the distance yet to be covered will represent the portion of
>   the dasha of Mars that is yet to be experienced. The balance is
>   calculated on the basis of the rule of three only in the case of the
>   first mahadasha; the subsequent mahadashas will have their full quota.
>   The balance mahadasha at birth on the basis of the exact longitude of
>   the Moon can be ascertained by using the ready reckoner provided in
>   all Panchangas. The Antra-dashas or the sub-periods and the
>   Prayantra-dashas of each planet is calculated on pro-rata basis in
>   proportion of the years allotted to them in the 120 years cycle of
>   Vimshottari dasha system.:253 Saravali insists that the sign occupied
>   by the Moon and the influences exercised on it by other planets
>   through aspects etc.; at the time of the commencement of its mahadasa
>   should be noted and examined, the same principle should also be
>   applied to other mahadasa lords. If at the time of the commencement of
>   the mahadasa its lord is in the lagna or in benefic or friendly vargas
>   or in an upachyasthana from the Birth ascendant or if the Moon
>   occupies the friendly sign or exaltation sign of the lord of the
>   mahadasa or is in an upachyasthana from the mahadasa lord and the
>   mahadasa lord is in a trine from the Moon then the mahadasa will give
>   exceptionally good results. ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasha_(astrology)))

[image]

Table [source](http://www.astroaura.net/dasa-bhukti-periods.html)